# Apache Artemis V 2.1.0

Tags: stomp, spring-websocket, activemq-artemis

I was using Artemis 1.5.3 and my addressing scheme was jms.topic.xxx for pub-sub and jms.queue.xxx for point to point and all worked great. However I switch to version 2.1.0 and the jms.topic.xxx work like a point to point routing, meaning not all subscribers receive the message. Previously, I was using ActiveMQ and their naming prefix was /topic.xxx and /queue.xxx. I also tried setting the multicast config in broker.xml per activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/2.1.0/address-model.html but Artemis is complaining and will not start. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what the actual errors are in the logs, I am going to assume that your instance is not starting up because of the way that you are defining your queues and/or topics. In version 2.x and newer, Artemis changed the way you define a queue or topic (They switched to an Address Model http://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/2.1.0/address-model.html).  Below is an example.  I hope this helps.

….. rest of broker.xml configuration

```
  <addresses>
     <!-- default queues for artemis -->
     <address name="DLQ">
        <anycast>
           <queue name="DLQ" />
        </anycast>
     </address>
     <address name="ExpiryQueue">
        <anycast>
           <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
        </anycast>
     </address>

     <!-- Define topics -->
     <address name="SomeTestTopic">
        <multicast/>
     </address>

     <!-- Define queues -->
     <address name="RequestReplyQueue">
        <anycast>
           <queue name="RequestReplyQueue" />
        </anycast>
     </address>

  </addresses>
```

Comment: Thanks Celias for the quick response, for the multicast definition, can I do something like jms.topic.# for wildcard to stay backward compatible with existing clients, thus jms.topic.stock.quote will result in a multicast? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I know in my example, I had name="SomeTestTopic", but for hierarchical naming, you would use name="stock.quote" and the wild card jms.topic.# or jms.topic.stock.# will work

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks. I will give it a try and update this thread.

Comment: I add the address settings below and have three clients subscribed to jms.topic.stocks.ibm
however, they are receiving the messages in anycast manner, it load balances across the 3 clients, I was expecting that that all 3 clients would have received the message as a broadcast:

Comment: here is a snippet of the wild card I add

 <addresses> 
...
       <!-- Define topics --> 
       <address name="jms.topic.#"> 
        <multicast/>         
       </address> 
 ...
</addresses>

However- if I set the address name above as jms.topic.stock.ibm then all three clients receive the message broadcast (pub/sub)

Comment: If you use anycast, it will behave as a queue.  That is a behavior that I have noticed, even if the destination is created as a topic.  When configuring through the broker, you need to use multicast for a topic.  When I first moved to artemis and was getting use to the new address model, this was something that I noticed.  I haven't had the chance to open a jira ticket to get a better understand of the behavior of using an anycast address, but in jms, using a topic destination

Comment: thanks for the help and the quick response.
I down grade from 2.1.0 to 1.5.5 until the pub/sub works since every use case for me depends on multicast and dynamic creation of topics.

Comment: No problem.  Just as an FYI, in the 2.1.0 download, there is an example apache-artemis-2.1.0\examples\features\standard\topic-hierarchies.  This example creates a bunch of topics, dynamically.  It uses a maven project.  I also stuck with 1.5.5 for close to the same reasons.

Comment: Regarding a design of many vs less topics, I am not sure what's the best approach, I have 10K users and each subscribes to 5 topics for a total of 50K topics, or I can change it so that each user subscribe to one topic for a total of 10K topics and use a payloadType attribute in the message to differentiate the type of message which will dictate the routing or how to process the message. Basically, 10K topics with alot of message flow vs 50K topics with small message flow. Which is more salable and overall a better approach? Thanks

Comment: With something like that, I would look into using selectors instead of creating all of those topics. Take a look at
 http://timjansen.github.io/jarfiller/guide/jms/selectors.xhtml for examples of filtering Topics using selectors.

Comment: I am using STOMP over websocket and the payload is json, I tried the header/selector approach in the past which work. Basically, one topic for all 10K connected clients and used a selector for routing. My 'issue' with that is if a subscription does not include this selector, example userToken=<a unique identifier> then that subscription will receive all messages even the ones that are not intended for him, which is a show stopper for using selectors since this is a public facing app.

Comment: I am not sure what your business rules.  It sounds like you "require" a selector.  If that is the case, look into https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/artemis-server/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/server/plugin/ActiveMQServerPlugin.java.   http://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/2.1.0/broker-plugins.html.  You might be able to create a plugin and implement beforeCreateConsumer and throw an exception out if you don't have a valid filterString.

Comment: Thanks Celias- so this will enable us to use one topic and use selectors to route the messages accordingly. I will make the necessary changes and update this thread.

Comment: I recently upgraded to version 2.2.0 from 1.5.5.

Comment: I recently upgraded to version 2.2.0 from 1.5.5. However, jms.topic is not acting as a broadcast to all subscribers. example, I have 5 client connected to jms.topic.test and I published a message to this topic, my expectation was that all five clients would have received this message but only one client received it, then the second client receive the next message and so on, this jms.topic.test seem to be acting like a queue (jms.queue.test). Note that this worked well with 1.5.5. Any help would be much appreciated since I need pub/sub for my use cases.